# App delegate variable returning nil despite being initialised

Tags: ios

In the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method in the App Delegate, a string, `myString` is initialised with a string retrieved from `NSUserDefaults` (confirmed with an `NSLog`). I have multiple view controllers in this tab-based project, and all of them are accessing the app delegate variables just fine, apart from one. The only difference between this view controller and the others is that it is a `UIViewController` as opposed to a `UITableViewController` (though the latter inherited).

In the `UIViewController`'s initialisation I've put:

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        self.appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
        if (self.appDelegate.myString == nil)
            NSLog(@"nil");
        }
    return self;
}
```

The strange part: in the `initWithNibName` method, `myString` (and all other variables in the app delegate) is `nil`. However when I fire this in the `viewDidAppear` method, it isn't `nil` (and I get the correct string). Furthermore it returns `nil` in the `viewDidLoad` method too. So I tried initialising `self.appDelegate` in `viewDidLoad` and then checking the string but it still returns `nil`.

I've gone wrong somewhere but can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just an oversight. I initialised the view controller before retrieving the variable from `NSUserDefaults`.